# $n$-Queens problem without backtracking

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Im wondering if there were ways to do the $n$-queens/ or $8$ queens problem without back tracking.

I currently know how to create it with backtracking though I'm looking for other ways to see if it works.

to say there is like $n=4$ and $155$ nodes must be  checked..

Comment: I suggest you explain what the problem is and what backtracking is.

Comment: Of course you can do it without backtracking.  You can generate every possible distribution of $n$ queens and test each one.  That's significantly less efficient than backtracking though.

Comment: Here is the [Wikipedia page on the n-queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) ... go to the 'Explicit Solutions' section for an easy algorithm that quickly lays out a solution for any $n$ without any trial and error at all.